# How can I sort the result of array_count_values()?

Tags: php, function, sorting

[Here](https://3v4l.org/PTPVN) is my code:

```
<?php
$array = array("world", 1, "hello", 1, "hello", "hello", "how");
$new_array = array_count_values($array);
print_r($new_array);
?>

/* Output:
Array
(
    [world] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [hello] => 3
    [how] => 1
)
```

Now I want to sort the result based on the new array's value. So this is expected output:

```
/* Expected Output:
Array
(
    [hello] => 3
    [1] => 2
    [world] => 1
    [how] => 1
)
```

How can I do that?

**Note:** The order for the same values doesn't matter.

Comment: Try asort http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php OR arsort http://php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php

Comment: use arsort() to sort the array by its values

Answer (score 8):

You can make use of [arsort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php) to sort the array by its value:

```
<?php
$array = array("world", 1, "hello", 1, "hello", "hello", "how");
$new_array = array_count_values($array);
arsort($new_array, SORT_NUMERIC);
print_r($new_array);
?>
```

which will output:

```
Array
(
    [hello] => 3
    [1] => 2
    [world] => 1
    [how] => 1
)
```

Comment: thank you .. upvote. Just I don't know why [it sorts as **asc** for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GspqI.png). Do you know how can I make it **desc** ?

Comment: Sorry, a typo in code. should be `arsort()`.

Answer (score 0):

Pleas try below code

```
    <?php

    $array = array("world", 1, "hello", 1, "hello", "hello", "how");

    $new_array = array_count_values($array);
    asort($new_array);
    print_r($new_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `arsort($new_array);` for sort in desc order and `asort($new_array);` for asc order